# why does addEventListener added via inline onclick fire referenced function immediatly?

Tags: javascript

During a recent project I have inherited some code that has raised some questions for me.

Could anybody explain why adding an event listener from an inline onclick function immediately fires the function referenced in the addEventListner()?

```js
function refFunction() {
  console.log("Test Function");

  if (document.removeEventListener) {
    document.removeEventListener('click', refFunction, false);
  } else if (document.detachEvent) {
    document.detachEvent('onclick', refFunction);
  }
}

function addEvtLstnr() {
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('click', refFunction, false);
  } else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent('onclick', refFunction);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Add Evt listener" onClick="addEvtLstnr();">
```

Please see a JSfiddle here : [Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajkhtf7q/2/)

The effect I would like is to add the event handler with the inline onclick of the button, but for it not to fire the referenced function immediately.

Any help is appreciated,
J.

Comment: @RobG that's a controversial advice: why to propagate an event at all if it's not what a developer wants.

Comment: @zerkms—oops, changed comment to an answer. Using a timeout avoids the issue, an alternative is to stop propagation of the event, but there may be other listeners that want to respond. Really it's up to the OP to determine which is the better approach. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Reading your code and reading your requirement explained in words is contradictory and reciprocally dismissive.

Reading you code reveals that your aim is to use an input button to assign an event to a document element which will fire only once. i.e.:  removed immediately after it has been fired. As in: https://jsfiddle.net/ajkhtf7q/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listener is added to the document when the button is clicked. The click event then bubbles up to the document, firing the listener.

To avoid that, use a timeout to add the listener so the event has finished bubbling before it's added.

Alternatively, stop propagation of the event so it doesn't bubble.

```js
function refFunction() {
  console.log("Test Function");

  if (document.removeEventListener) {
    document.removeEventListener('click', refFunction, false);
  } else if (document.detachEvent) {
    document.detachEvent('onclick', refFunction);
  }
}

function addEvtLstnr() {
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('click', refFunction, false);
  } else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent('onclick', refFunction);
  }
}
```

```html
// Call addEvtLstnr after a pause so event finishes bubbling before listener added
<input type="button" value="Add Evt listener" onclick="setTimeout(addEvtLstnr, 0);">

// Stop propagation of the event so that it doesn't reach the listener
<input type="button" value="Add Evt listener 2" onclick="addEvtLstnr();event.stopPropagation();">
```

BTW, function declarations are not terminated with a semicolon. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Quote: *"Could anybody explain why adding an event listener from an inline onclick function immediately fires the function referenced in the addEventListner()?"*

That's not exactly true, the event has to ***propagate*** through quite a few elements in order to be able to finally reach and fire at the *root element* at which you actually added the event listener.

The root element will receive the click event at your input element after it has been assigned a click event listener and is, therefore, required to fire it as prescribed.